# Pandas: how to select specific values from a column and aggregate like in SQL?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have this **drinks_table**, and my question is:

Who drinks more beer and wine, the US or Spain?

[image]

A SQL query would be

```
SELECT country, 
       sum(litres_consumed) AS litres_consumed
       FROM drinks_table
       WHERE country IN ('US', 'Spain')
       AND drinks IN ('beer', 'wine')
GROUP BY country
```

Which would give me

[image]

How do I do this in Pandas?

So far I have

```
df.groupby(['country', 'litres_consumed']).size()
```

...but this gives me values for Italy as well, which I don't want

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the DataFrame in a way that can be copied into a Python script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so in two easy steps:

```
beer_wine = df[df.drinks.isin(['beer', 'wine'])
```

followed by

```
beer_wine.liters_consumed.groupby(beer_wine.country).sum()
```

---

Alternatively, you can aggregate a bit more than you want, but use only a single line:

```
df.liters_consumed.groupby([df.country, df.drinks.isin(['beer', 'wine']]).sum()
```